# Index.cshtml(7,16): error CS0103: The name 'Request' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, .net, razor, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am working on learning ASP .NET MVC using the dot net core framework. I have reached the point where I am trying to implement a `cshtml` file using some razor code. But I am getting a error when making the request.

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Compilation.CompilationFailedException:
>   One or more compilation failures occurred:
>   /Views/Shared/Index.cshtml(5,4): error CS0103: The name 'IsPost' does
>   not exist in the current context /Views/Shared/Index.cshtml(7,16):
>   error CS0103: The name 'Request' does not exist in the current context
>   /Views/Shared/Index.cshtml(8,16): error CS0103: The name 'Request'
>   does not exist in the current context

My initial thought is that I am missing a reference, but I am not seeing what I would be missing. I have tried removing the razor code and then the page loads correctly.

**project.json**

```
    {
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "type": "platform"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.CommandLine": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools" : "1.0.0-preview2-final"

  },

  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },

  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },

  "runtimeOptions": {
    "configProperties": {
      "System.GC.Server": true
    }
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "web.config"
    ]
  },

  "scripts": {
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  },

  "tooling": {
    "defaultNamespace": "MVCWebAPI"
  }
}
```

**index.cshtml**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
@{
var totalMessage = "";
if(IsPost)
    {
    var num1 = Request["text1"];
    var num2 = Request["text2"];
    var total = num1.AsInt() + num2.AsInt();
    totalMessage = "Total = " + total;
    }
}

<html>
<body style="background-color: beige; font-family: Verdana, Arial;">
<form action="" method="post">
<p><label for="text1">First Number:</label><br>
<input type="text" name="text1"></p>
<p><label for="text2">Second Number:</label><br>
<input type="text" name="text2"></p>
<p><input type="submit" value=" Add "></p>
</form>
<p>@totalMessage</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks

Comment: Should that part be really in the View ? I think you misunderstood the purpose of MVC here. That data should be passed from the controller.

Comment: @user3185569 So the cshtml was directly from a tutorial about razor. I was more focused on getting the web page to load. My concern was that if the IsPost and Request aren't allowing the file to compile then I will have issues with other aspects of razor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use your controller to prepare your data and pass them to your view for displaying.

For instance, Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index(){
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(ViewModelThatSuitsYourNeeds vm){
//Do your magic here
ResultViemModel resultVM= //your magic;
return View(vm);
}
```

But honestly, try to get a better look at MVC first, the only logic in your view should be the logic needed to display your data (eg: a foreach-loop to iterate trough a collection).

Also, take a look at @html-helpers:
You don't have to create a , you can use

```
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
```

Of course, then I assume you pass a model to your View, which is a different story.

To get you started with MVC, you could create a simple model, use EF code-first to create the database and then add a "Controller with Views, using Entity Framework", based on that simple model and the created context, which will scaffold you a useful example.

Edit:
I looked at the tutorial myself and made the “app” myself (VS 2015, 4.5.2), these are the steps I followed:
-Create an Empty asp.net web-application, no references/folders or Authentication.
-Create the folder Controllers and add a HomeController (empty one)
-Wait till the scaffolding is done
-Add a view (Index.cshtml) to the Views-folder, without a model, but with the layout-page
-Copy the code from W3S, but strip the markup that already is included in the layout-page (like Body):

```
    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    }

    <h2>Index</h2>

    @{
        var totalMessage = "";
        if (IsPost)
        {
            var num1 = Request["text1"];
            var num2 = Request["text2"];
            var total = num1.AsInt() + num2.AsInt();
            totalMessage = "Total = " + total;
        }
    }

        <form action="" method="post">
            <p>
                <label for="text1">First Number:</label><br>
                <input type="text" name="text1">
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for="text2">Second Number:</label><br>
                <input type="text" name="text2">
            </p>
            <p><input type="submit" value=" Add "></p>
        </form>
        <p>@totalMessage</p>
```

-Run it, works fine here

If it doesn’t work on your machine, maybe consider uploading the project, makes it easier to check!

Comment: Passing in data is my plan for this. I just wanted to get the example working first. I'll try changing the index file so that it is doing something more realistic.

Comment: W3S isn't really suited for learning ASP.NET MVC in my not so humble opinion. The try-it editor and C# don't really like each other (the editor works fine for most css, html & js though). This one (https://blog.udemy.com/a-step-by-step-asp-net-tutorial-for-beginners/) maybe isn't the best either, but it seems like a detailed one that explains the basic aspects of MVC.

Comment: Thanks I will take a look at the page. At this point I have a model and controller. I just wanted to make a decent page to display the data.

Comment: @Firestone I followed the tutorial (well, I copied the code from the try-it editor, didn't really look at the rest of the tutorial).   I didn't bother to change the routing, so you might want to browse to http://localhost:1234/Home/Index to get the page to display.

Comment: so based on the error i was getting I dont think the issue is the navigation. My thought is it has to do with the dot net core framework not having everything built in. Since the cshtml file is failing to compile on my machine (using dot net core) but works fine on yours,  my guess is it is just a current limitation. Either way i implemented a file that was closer to what i needed that works fine.